# JavaScript function that returns all permutations

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion, parameters

I've been trying to make a function that generates all the permutations of the numbers from 0 to num and stores them in a multidimensional array. I want to store in the combinations variable something like:

```
 [ [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 1, 3, 2 ],
    [ 2, 1, 3 ],
    [ 3, 1, 2 ],
wrongly     [ 2, 3, 1 ],
    [ 3, 2, 1 ] ]
```

but instead I get:

```
[ [ 3, 2, 1 ],
  [ 3, 2, 1 ],
  [ 3, 2, 1 ],
  [ 3, 2, 1 ],
  [ 3, 2, 1 ],
  [ 3, 2, 1 ] ]
```

My function is:

```js
var combinations = [];

function comb(num, index, list, used) {
  if (num == index)
    combinations.push(list);
  else {
    for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
      if (!used[i]) {
        list[i] = index + 1;
        used[i] = true;
        comb(num, index + 1, list, used);
        used[i] = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I usually program with C++, so I think that I am using the arrays wrongly.

Comment: It is odd to call a function intended to generate permutations `combinations`, since  permutations and combinations are different types of combinatorial objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the `list` array you pass into your recursive call is going to be changed as it is essentially passed by reference, so `list` will lose its previous combinations. Instead, you can make a copy of the array before you pass it into your recursive call using the spread syntax (`...`).

See working example below:

```js
var combinations = [];

function comb(num, index, list, used) {
  if (num == index)
    combinations.push(list);
  else {
    for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
      if (!used[i]) {
        list[i] = index + 1;
        used[i] = true;
        comb(num, index + 1, [...list], used);
        used[i] = false;
      }
    }
  }
}

comb(3, 0, [], []);
console.log(combinations); // [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[3,1,2],[2,3,1],[3,2,1]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```